# UFC rules on passive fighting

Tags: ufc

In UFC Fight Night 111 in Singapore between Holm and Correia it was a very defensive, tactical fight. In the third round the referee said to both fighters "I understand your game plan but we have to get something going here". In other words he was saying "you both aren't attacking enough".

That to me raises some interesting questions:
[1] is this the limit to what the referee can do under UFC rules?
[2] If both fighters just kept standing off what could he do? Especially with both fighters doing it. Does he have the power to stop the fight and declare a no contest or draw because it's so passive?